# A question related to the minimality of generators of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am currently working on the following exercise problem from David Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra With A View Towards Algebraic Geometry.*

> **Exercise 4.9** Consider a local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $m$. Let $I\subset R$ and $x\in m$ a nonzero divisor on $R/I.$ My goal is to show that a minimal set of generators for $I$ maps to a minimal generating set for the image of $I$ in $R/(x)$.

I am trying to prove this claim *via* *Nakayama's Lemma*, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Any hint/help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I believe $I/xI=I/((x)\cap I)$ is not necessarily true if $x$ is a zero divisor, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $I/xI=I/((x)\cap I)$, applying Nakayama's lemma to $I$ and $I/xI$ gives us the desired result.