# A question related to a counterexample to a claim

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

This is related to one of my previous questions.

> *Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathcal{M}$. Let
> $I\subset R$ be an ideal and $x\in \mathcal{M}$ a nonzero divisor on
> $R/I$. Then, if $I$ has a minimal set of generators, then it maps to a
> minimal generating set for the image of $I$ in $R/(x)$.*

I can see how the assumption that $x$ is a nonzero divisor was crucial in proving the above statement, but I am struggling to think of an example where the claim fails when $x$ is a zero divisor.

Any help/hint will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your related question (which you should definitely have linked in the first place, as it has the context you are talking about) you need to know that $x$ is a non-zero divisor on $R/I$ to show that $(x)\cap I\subseteq xI$.

For example, in $R=F[[x]]$, if $I=(x^2)$ then $(x^2)=(x)\cap I\nsubseteq xI=(x^3)$.

Comment: My apologies, I should have mentioned the context clearly. Thank you.